# CSV file written but output is not correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I used python 3.5 to write a CSV file using the information from a previous CSV file. Here is an input line from the first file:

```
John    Smith   johnsmith@gmail.com Yellow  Johnsmith, LLC
```

The format is first name, last name, email, favorite color, and company. The delimiter for this file is comma. The next CSV file will have all the same information but the delimiter will be changed from commas to tabs. Heres the script I wrote:

```
import csv
with open('combinedtable.csv','r') as csv_file, open('alteredcombinedtable.csv','w') as csv_file2:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file2, delimiter='\t')
    for row in csv_file:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

The script created the CSV file but the output was not correct. Here is what it looks like:

```
"f  i   r   s   t   n   a   m   e   "   "   l   a   s   t   n   a   m   e   "   "   e   m   a   i   l   a   d   d   r   e   s   s   "   "   f   a   v   o   r   i   t   e   c   o   l   o   r   "   "   c   o   m   p   a   n   y   """
```

It only has the headers and they're separated like this when pasted from the csv file. Would anyone be able to explain why this output occurred?

Comment: The for statement is wrong. You should be iterating over csv_reader.

Comment: I think @Q-life's is correct. Also note that you should include a `newline=''` keyword argument when you `open()` csv files for reading or writing as shown in the examples in the module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents).

Comment: Thanks, both of your recommendations worked out perfectly and I was able to correctly write my code. Really appreciate it!